# Django urls, different regex?

Tags: python, regex, django, url

My urlconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'ping.views.services', name='services'),
    url(r'^ajax/status/(?P<id>[-\d]+)', 'ping.views.ajx_status', name='ajx_status'),
    url(r'^ajax/status/(?P<type>[-\w]+)/(?P<id>[-\d]+)(?:\?callback=(?P<callback>[-\w]+)&[_=0-9]+)?$', 'ping.views.ajx_status', name='ajx_status'),
)
```

Link was: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/status/jsonp/1?callback=jQuery110208076630807481706_1386460596798&_=1386460596799`

Output:

```
def ajx_status(request, id, type,callback):
    print id,type,callback
```

log:

```
1 jsonp None
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:903: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Ping.timestamp received a naive datetime (2013-12-08 18:12:33.831348) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)

[08/Dec/2013 18:12:34] "GET /ajax/status/jsonp/1?callback=jQuery110208076630807481706_1386460596798&_=1386460596799 HTTP/1.1" 200 433
```

Text in "raw" python, works:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"^/ajax/status/(?P<type>[-\w]+)/(?P<id>[-\d]+)(?:\?callback=(?P<callback>[-\w]+)&[_=0-9]+)?")

r = regex.search("/ajax/status/jsonp/1?callback=jQuery110208076630807481706_1386460596798&_=1386460596799")

r.groupdict()

{'callback': 'jQuery110208076630807481706_1386460596798', 'type': 'jsonp', 'id': '1'}
```

Googled a few hours about this curious, that Django dosen't match the url on the same way how in python. Any ideas how it does not work and callback is always None ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the path part of the URL is matched against the urlpattern. The query string is available in the view thru `request.GET`

Answer (score 0):

In the Django url-config, there is no need to match the Query String in the url. You can query the query string data like `request.GET.get('query_string_key')`.

For example:

```
request.GET.get("page")
```

In the `urls.py` you can write the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^ajax/status/(?P<type>[-\w]+)/(?P<id>[-\d]+)/$', 'ping.views.ajx_status', name='ajx_status'),
)
```